# Using multiple filters in .Filter() with GraphServiceClient in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm unable to combine filters. I get an error from Graph when I try to do so. Examples as below:

This works:

```
var users = await client.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"userType eq 'Member'")
                    .Select(u => new
                    {
                        u.DisplayName,
                        u.UserType,
                        u.SignInActivity,
                    })
                    .GetAsync();
```

This also works:

```
var users = await client.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-11-01T00:00:00Z")
                    .Select(u => new
                    {
                        u.DisplayName,
                        u.UserType,
                        u.SignInActivity,
                    })
                    .GetAsync();
```

However if I combine the filters, it does not:

```
var user = await client.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"userType eq 'Member' and signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-11-01T00:00:00Z")
                    .Select(u => new
                    {
                        u.DisplayName,
                        u.UserType,
                        u.SignInActivity,
                    })
                    .GetAsync();
```

I get the error `Filter not supported.`. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you made everything right. It's just the Graph API. It doesn't support all kinds of filter combinations (especially when using *deeper* properties like your last sign in date). You just have to pick one of them and make the other filter on the client side (and don't forget the nextLink in the retrieved collection to really get all users ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) `signInActivity` property supports `$filter` but, not with any other filterable properties.

> Returned only on $select. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le) but, not with any other filterable properties. Note: Details for this property require an Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license and the AuditLog.Read.All permission.